# Probability of choosing a base successfully in Pollard p-1 factorization method

Tags: cryptanalysis, factoring

In a problem about pollard p-1 factorization method, where $n=pq$.
We choose some random base $a$ , and an exponent $B$, where hopefully $p-1$ has small prime factors, and if so we hope to estimate $p = \gcd(a^B-1,n)$.

We wish to estimate the probability that for a given exponent $B$, a randomly chosen base $a$ satisfies that $p$ divides $a^B-1$ and $q$ doesn‘t divide $a^B-1$. We assume that the prime factorizations of $p-1,q-1,\text{ and } B$ are known. How can I estimate the probability of success?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $p-1$ method works, by definition, whenever the [multiplicative order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order) of $a$ modulo $p$ is a divisor of $B$. If $B$ is a multiple of $p-1$, that is, the maximum possible multiplicative order of $a$, the probability is $1$.

We are concerned, then, with the case where $B$ does *not* contain every divisor of $p-1$. If it contains none of them, the probability is $0$.

The key challenge here is, having a number $d$ corresponding to the factors of of $p-1$ missing from $B$, to count the number of elements of $\mathbb{F}_p^{\ast}$ whose order is $(p-1)/d$ or any of its divisors. Those elements are precisely the ones for which those missing factors from their order do not affect the success of the factorization.
If $d=1$, the number of elements is $p-1$, that is, the whole range. If $d = 2$, this number is the number of elements such that $a^{(p-1)/2} = 1$, that is, the number of [quadratic residues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#Prime_modulus) modulo $p$ (excluding 0), which happens to be $(p-1)/2$.

More generally, since $\mathbb{F}_p^{\ast}$ is cyclic every element can be represented as $g^e$, for some [primitive element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_(finite_field)) $g$ and an exponent $e$. Our goal is to count the number of solutions $e$ to
$$
g^{e(p-1)/d} = 1 \pmod{p}\,,
$$
or in other words
$$
e(p-1)/d = 0 \pmod{p-1}\,,
$$
which we can see is the number of multiples of $d$ up to $p-1$, i.e., $\frac{p-1}{d}$.

Let $d$ be product of factors of $p-1$ that $B$ does not contain, i.e., $d = \frac{p-1}{\gcd(p-1, B)}$. Then the probability of the order of a randomly selected $a$ splitting $n$ is given by
$$
\frac{(p-1)/d}{p-1} = \frac{1}{d}\,.
$$

For example, suppose $p = 15554690395797258751$. Now suppose $B$ contains all the factors of $p-1 = 2\cdot 3 \cdot 5^4 \cdot 11 \cdot 1021 \cdot 25013 \cdot 14765423$ except $2$. Then the probability that $p-1$ factorization works is $1/2$. If $B$ on the other hand is too low and doesn't include $14765423$, which is the more likely case, the factorization probability becomes $1/14765423$.

For $q-1$ the same considerations apply. However, when considering both $p-1$ and $q-1$ at the same time, one needs to subtract the case where both succeed, in which case there is also no factorization. Like above, suppose $d_1$ are the missing $p-1$ factors from $B$, and $d_2$ the ones from $q-1$. Then we have a probability of success
$$
\frac{1}{d_1}\left(1 - \frac{1}{d_2}\right) + \frac{1}{d_2}\left(1 - \frac{1}{d_1}\right) = \frac{1}{d_1} + \frac{1}{d_2} - \frac{2}{d_1d_2}\,,
$$
that is, $p-1$ succeeds and $q-1$ fails, or $q-1$ succeeds and $p-1$ fails.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on how  you reached (p-1)/d using Lagrange’s theorem? Thanks

Comment: For example, if we take p=19 and d =6, then we have ord(1)=1, ord(2,3,10,19,14,15)=18, ord(4,5,6,9,16,17)=9, ord(7,11)=3, ord(8,12)=6, ord(18)=2. Thus, the number of elements whose order does not divide d is 12 which is not equal to (p-1)/d.

Comment: In your example we have $p-1 = 2\cdot 3^2$ and we are missing from $B$ $d = 6 = 2\cdot 3$. But this means that $B = 3\cdot \dots$, since we are only missing one of the powers of $3$. So what we need for success is that the order of $a$ not be a multiple of $2$ *and* $3^{2}$, of which there are $3 = 18/6$ elements, $\{1,7,11\}$. My explanation above is clearly incomplete, since it only holds for primes without powers, but I believe the result itself is correct. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Edited things to make more sense.

Comment: I'm confused about the third paragraph, which is the relation between $d$ the number of missing factors of $B$ and $(p-1)/d$. Why the number of the missing factors have order $(p-1)/d$

Comment: If $B$ is missing a factor $d$ of $p-1$, then $a^B \bmod p$ is equivalent to $a^{(p-1)/d \cdot \dots} \bmod p$. So what we're counting is the number of elements such that $a^{(p-1)/d} = 1 \bmod p$, i.e., the number of elements of order (at most) $(p-1)/d$.

Comment: I think _having a number $d$ corresponding to the missing factors_ confuses me. I read it like there are $d$ factors missing. Now I can see better that $d \nmid B$ is not the size of the set $\{d\mid d \nmid B \}$.

Comment: Let $d$ be the product of factors of $p−1$ that $B$ does not contain... This is true if $d$ is prime, however, then $d$ is not a prime the product misses some number like let $2$ and $3$ is missing, however, the product $d =  6$ doesn't involve $2,4,9,$,etc. Don't we need the inclusion-exclusion there?

Comment: I don't understand your point. For any element, $a^{p-1} = 1$. If $B$ is missing 2 and 3, i.e., $d=6$, then what you are computing instead (ignoring the non-divisors of $p-1$ in $B$) is $a^{(p-1)/6}$, because every other divisor of $p-1$ is already in there. So the method will work for elements such that $a^{(p-1)/6} = 1$. Note that $d$ and $p-1$ can share factors, for example you could have $p-1 = 2^5 3^3 5^4$ and $d = 10$, which would imply $B = 2^4 3^3 5^3 \cdot \dots$, in which case the method would work when $a^{2^4 3^3 5^3} = a^{(p-1)/10} = 1$.